# Determine max size & min size in a column with alphanumeric values

Tags: excel, vba

[image: I tried one of the suggested method below:]
Ex.

1. 36R
2. 38R
3. 40S
4. 40M
5. 40L

So the Highest size is 40L & Lowest size is 36R

please help me with this.

Comment: Why is 40L higher than 40M?

Comment: Trouser sizes? S(hort)/M(edium)/R(egular)/L(ong)?. Need to know the correct order for these anyway.

Comment: Yes actually its Trouser sizes order will be same S(hort)/M(edium)/R(egular)/L(ong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this any kind of clothes sizes, then you may create your own formula.

First, you need to rank each size (R,S,L,M, and so on), and assign them an *unique numeric** value for each one of them:

[image]

Then you can do an array formula to get the max and min values:

[image]

My formula to get max size is:

```
=LEFT(MAX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE ($A$1:$A$5;G1;H1);G2;H2);G3;H3);G4;H4)*1);2)&VLOOKUP(1*RIGHT(MAX(SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE ($A$1:$A$5;G1;H1);G2;H2);G3;H3);G4;H4)*1);1);H1:I4;2;FALSE)
```

To get min size is exactly the same, just using MIN instead of max.

> Because this is an array formula, it must be entered with
> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work.

This is how it works:

1. `MAX(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE ($A$1:$A$5;G1;H1);G2;H2);G3;H3);G4;H4)*1)` will get the max value of the sizes, after replacing each letter with a numeric value.
2. Then we get the first 2 chars of the previous value.
3. We concatenate step 2 with a VLOOKUP that will take the third char of value from step 1, and will find the letter related.

I've uploaded to my Gdrive a file example, so you can check the formulas: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13vnBF651FYl3ILVvM_h9E-uS_Ttqiu9t/view?usp=sharing

**UPDATE:**
Testing with values `36R,34R,42R,32L` i get this:
[image]

Same formula. I just created a table, so MAX and MIN range updates instantly, but formula is the same.

Comment: I wish in Excel there was a way of doing multiple substitutions without having to have a whole chain of SUBSTITUE.

Comment: "SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE (SUBSTITUTE " looks really messy.

Comment: Indeed it does. With VBA it could be done easier, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,but actually its showing error due to ";" used in the ranges,its an array formula so I used Ctrl+Shift+Enter ,still its same ,any suggestion will be appreciated ,Thanks.

Comment: @AkshayJadhav using `;` or `,` depends on your regional settings. Just replace each `;` with `,`. OR download the example provided in the link

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns ,Gsheet asking for the permission & even replacing the ';' this to ',' is showing #Name Thanks

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns ,My bad there was some extra spaces in the formulas ,due to which it was showing error its working now ,but I've given I/P as `36R ,34R,42R,34L` so it has to show `42R`as a Max size but its showing `34R`.

Comment: Did you download the file I've attached? Make a test there

Comment: Its asking permission for access,I already raised request for the permission

Comment: @AkshayJadhav My bad, i tought it was a public link. Try this one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hanyKKb_-U8MLwLlho52awBqhMiqHBDM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns thanks its opened ,but its working in google spreadsheet ,i'm developing a template in excel there its not working

Comment: *it's not working* is too broad. Maybe you should edit your question, and add images explaining what is not working. If you added new sizes, make sure you change the range of VLOOKUP and so on.

Comment: @ Foxfire And Burns And Burns I appreciate your help & patients too ,thanks for the suggestion ,here I've edited the question & attached image of the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217074/discussion-between-akshay-jadhav-and-foxfire-and-burns-and-burns).

Comment: @ Foxfire And Burns And Burns,Thank you so much it worked !!

Comment: @AkshayJadhav Glad to help. Hope you can adapt this to your needs. If this answer helped, please, mark it as correct so the question can be closed, and be helpful for other users.

Answer (score 2):

In my formula I temporarily substitute -

- R for .1
- S for .2
- M for .3
- L for .4

So

- 32L would become 32.3
- 24R would become 24.1

Then once I have applied the MAX function I reverse all the substitutions. So -

- .1 becomes R
- .2 becomes S
- .3 becomes M
- .4 becomes L

  =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MAX(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"L",".4"),"M",".3"),"S",".2"),"R",".1"))),".4","L"),".3","M"),".2","S"),".1","R")

Comment: Thanks for the response ,i tried this ,since I'm using Excel 2010 it shown me error for NumberValue() function instead i tried Value() function but its not showing the correct Max no. ,any suggestions please on this

Comment: I think arrays are handled differently in older versions of Excel. Are you still stuck on the issue?

Answer (score 2):

In general, what you need to do, whether it be by formulas or code, is split off the `RSML` from the number. Then sort by number and **custom** sort by the letters.

For the formula, I assumed that the number portion would always be two digits.  And I used a Table with structured references, although you could change to regular addressing if you prefer:

For a "single cell formula", if you have Excel O365 with the `SORTBY` function, you can use:

```
Lowest:   =INDEX(SORTBY(Table1[Sizes],MID(Table1[Sizes],1,2),1,MATCH(INDEX(MID(Table1[Sizes],{1,3},{2,1}),0,2),{"R";"S";"M";"L"},0),1),1)

Highest:  =INDEX(SORTBY(Table1[Sizes],MID(Table1[Sizes],1,2),1,MATCH(INDEX(MID(Table1[Sizes],{1,3},{2,1}),0,2),{"R";"S";"M";"L"},0),1),COUNTA(Table1[Sizes]))
```

[image]

Just for fun, (and for those who do not have the latest version of Excel) I decided to try doing this in `Power Query` *(available in Excel 2010+)*

The algorithm is basically the same, although the coding is different.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Sizes", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c)), {"Sizes.1", "Sizes.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{{"Sizes.1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Sizes.1", Order.Ascending}, each List.PositionOf({"S","R","M","L"}, [Sizes.2])}),

        Filter1 = Table.SelectRows(#"Sorted Rows", each [Sizes.1] =  
            List.First(Table.Column(#"Sorted Rows","Sizes.1" )) or [Sizes.1] =  List.Last(Table.Column(#"Sorted Rows","Sizes.1" ))),
        Filter2 = Table.SelectRows(Filter1, each [Sizes.2] =  
            List.First(Table.Column(Filter1,"Sizes.2" )) or [Sizes.2] =  List.Last(Table.Column(Filter1,"Sizes.2" ))),

    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Filter2, {{"Sizes.1", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Sizes.1", "Sizes.2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Sizes"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Index", 0, 1),
    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Rank", each if [Index] = 0  then "Lowest" else 
            if [Index]+1 = Table.RowCount(#"Added Index") then 
            "Highest" else 
            null),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([Rank] <> null)),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Rank", "Sizes"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

and, of course, the results are the same:

[image]